# How can I calculate the values of the four resistors in a Wheatstone bridge?

Tags: load-cell, wheatstone-bridge

I measured black-red = 400ohm, green-white = 350ohm in a 5kg loadcell.

How can I calculate the resistor values?

[image]

Comment: Does the bridge have a datasheet? Does it have a fifth resistor (in series with one of the input wires)?

Comment: Measurements are meaningless because of connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many strain gauges have gain calibration resistors in the excitation leads such as here: -

[image]

Image from [RS, Tedea Huntleigh Wire Lead Load Cell](https://export.rsdelivers.com/product/tedea-huntleigh/0240-0020-e002/tedea-huntleigh-wire-lead-load-cell-10c-40c/2060262). And, this means that the excitation leads measure a higher resistance than the output leads. Given also that 350 Ω is pretty commonplace for a strain gauge, it's likely that the measurement of 400 Ω is because of the 350 Ω gauges plus 25 Ω in each excitation lead.

- Resistance between A and C should be 287.5 Ω nominal
- Resistance between A and D should be 287.5 Ω nominal
- Resistance between F and C should be 287.5 Ω nominal
- Resistance between F and D should be 287.5 Ω nominal

[image]

$$R_{AC} = 25 + 350 || 1050$$

Comment: ok, i get it now, how did you calculate and got 287.5? I just got 290ohm AC, AD, FC, FD

Comment: guang ce yzc 1b 5kg loadcell

Comment: @TumenbayarMunkhjargal between B and C is a 350 ohm gauge in parallel with 3 series gauges of 350 ohm. That is a resistance of  262.5 ohms. Therefore between A and C is 262.5 ohm plus 25 ohm = 287.5 ohm.

Comment: could you please simplify that delta circuit into simple so I can understand it fully

Comment: I've added a picture @TumenbayarMunkhjargal

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution:

[image]

You could check by performing other measurements:

- between A and C = 312.5 \$\Omega\$
- between A and D = 312.5 \$\Omega\$
- between E and D = 262.5 \$\Omega\$
- between E and C = 262.5 \$\Omega\$

Just to be clear: if this is the topology you don't have access to node B.

> guang ce yzc 1b 5kg loadcell

Update: different to this [document](https://www.ardu.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Vejecelle-YZC-1B.pdf), which resembles a datasheet and was mentioned yesterday in another question, it seems that the internal configuration uses 2 series resistors, as detailed in Andy's answer.

[image]

Comment: it is physically loadcell 5kg, how to calculate it, not practically

Comment: A and C, AD, ED, EC are all 290ohm as I measured just now, I wonder why

Comment: @TumenbayarMunkhjargal looks like the answer you have been given is correct, with the tolerance of what you say you measured compared to the 287.5 ohms suggested.